# How to check if a trigger fires on INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

How do I determine whether a trigger is targeting INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements?

I've checked in `sys.triggers` and I can't see anything related to what operation the trigger fires on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sys.triggers` table does not expose this data, instead we have two options:

---

**OBJECTPROPERTY**

Using the [OBJECTPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql) metadata function we can return the action as a property as below:

```
OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsUpdateTrigger')
OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsInsertTrigger')
OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger')
```

This will return a simple bit value indicating whether the trigger fires on that particular action.

---

**sys.trigger_events**

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ca-es/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-trigger-events-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) this contains a row per event for which a trigger fires. Specifically the columns we're interested in are `type` and `type_desc`.

`type` is a foreign key to the `sys.trigger_event_types` table - `type_desc` seems to contain the `type_name` column from the `sys.trigger_event_types` table.

This data can be returned using the following script:

```
SELECT
    [o].[name]
   ,[t].[type_desc]
FROM
    [sys].[trigger_events] AS [t]
    INNER JOIN [sys].[objects] AS [o] ON
        [o].[object_id] = [t].[object_id]
WHERE
    [o].[name] = 'TriggerNameHere';
```